# Craft\EntryModel and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "siteUrl"

Tags: entrymodel, siteurl

Getting the above error when trying to add a new entry to a structure section.

The Section has an Entry URL Format of:

{siteUrl}/{slug}

In my general.php in the config folder I have:

```
return array(

    '*' => array(
            'omitScriptNameInUrls' => true,
        ),


    'local.ontherocks.dev' => array(
        'devMode' => true,
        'environmentVariables' => array(
            'basePath' => 'C:/Users/User/Documents/My Websites/Sitename/public/',
            'baseUrl'  => 'http://local.ontherocks.dev/',
            'siteUrl'  => 'http://local.ontherocks.dev/',
        )   
    )

);
```

I don't see why I am getting this error - I have the same set up in another site I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Environment variables are only available in specific settings, and Entry URL Formats are not one of them.

There’s no need to include your Site URL in there anyway, though. The field’s label might be a little misleading – it’s really more of a *URI* format than a *URL* format.

If you want your entries to get URLs like http://example.com/entry-slug, then all you need to put in your section’s Entry URL Format setting is:

```
{slug}
```

Comment: Thanks - changing that has removed the error.
I have it set like that in a previous site and it worked but must be something else to it.

Comment: @mmc501 Glad you’re all sorted. The only way it would work is if you had a custom field with the handle “siteUrl”.